# Redirect a subdomain to a new URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a client that had a main site in Joomla and a blog in WordPress. We just made everything one WordPress site.

What I need help with is redirecting the subdomain (e.g. blog.example.org) to the new URL (example.org/blog).

I believe this needs to get done with `.htaccess` and it needs to be integrated with the WordPress stuff, too.

Here's where I got so far:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.health-access.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/blog/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But it's not working.  Any thoughts and help are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the order:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.health-access.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/blog/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursubdomain\.yourdomain\.com$ [
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/?param=data&uparam2=data
```